# Jekyll: Looping with expired Dates

Tags: jekyll

So I'm trying to show the latest 5 upcoming events. I'm pulling everything form a data file. But I noticed that when an event expires and remains in the data file, that the homepage is showing 5 minus the amount of expired events.

For example, if there was 1 event that was expired the homepage would only show 4 of the upcoming events, instead of skipping the expired event and looping. Can anyone help? Thanks!

```
{% assign eventPost = site.data.events | sort: 'date' %}
            {% for event in eventPost limit:5 %}
            {% assign curDate = site.time | date: '%Y-%m-%d' %}
            {% assign postStartDate = event.date | date: '%Y-%m-%d' %}
            {% if postStartDate >= curDate %}
            <div class="content--block">
                <div class="event--info">
                    <p class="content--date">{{ event.date | date: '%B %-d, %Y' }}</p>
                    <h3 class="content--title">{{ event.title }}</h3>
                    {% if event.time %}
                    <p class="content--location"><strong>{{ event.location }}</strong> at <strong>{{ event.time }}</strong></p>
                    {% else %}
                    <p class="content--location"><strong>{{ event.location }}</strong></p>
                    {%  endif %}
                    {% if event.subheader %}
                    <p class="content--description">{{ event.subheader }}</p>
                    {% endif %}
                </div>
                {% if event.button == true %}
                <a href="{{ event.eventlink }}" target="_blank"><button class="outline">Attend</button></a>
                {% endif %}
            </div>
            {% endif %}
            {% endfor %}
```

Comment: So I realize this question is 4 years old...but wouldn't this approach require redeploying the site every time you wanted to update the upcoming event list, even if all you wanted to happen was for the date to roll over automatically?

Answer (score 2):

`{% for event in eventPost limit:5 %}` instructs liquid to create a temporary array with 5 first `eventPost` elements. Your loop is definitely looping over 5 elements and no more.

Use a counter instead. Note, I've sniped code in the print loop for brevity.

```
{% assign eventPost = site.data.events | sort: 'date' %}
{% assign eventsNumber = 5 %}
{% assign printedEvents = 0 %}

{% for event in eventPost %}
    {% assign curDate = site.time | date: '%Y-%m-%d' %}
    {% assign postStartDate = event.date | date: '%Y-%m-%d' %}
    {% if (postStartDate >= curDate) and (printedEvents < eventsNumber) %}
        {% assign printedEvents = printedEvents | plus: 1 %}
        <p>{{ event.date | date: '%B %-d, %Y' }} - {{ event.title }}</p>
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

You then just have to change the `eventsNumber` to change number of printed events.